# Detecting <CR> from incoming data using Serial Java

Tags: java, serial-port

I have a program that takes characters from the buffer to form a string.

My program is:

```
while (i < 5) {
    ch = inStream.read();
    buffer.append((char)ch);
    i++;
}
data = buffer.toString();
```

For my program above, I can only take 5 characters to form a string. What I want to do is have a variable length of string. The length of the string will depend on the detection of `<CR>`. The serial device I am using always terminates the data by `<CR>`. By doing it, my string can have any length.

Problem solved. Here's what I tried and worked perfectly - assuming 300 is my max and i want to detect /n as well.

My code:

```
while (i < 300) {
    ch = inStream.read();
    if ((ch=='\r')||(ch=='\n')) {
        i = 300;
    }
    buffer.append((char)ch);
    i++;
}
data = buffer.toString();
```

Comment: Why do you need that `i` variable??

Comment: It's a limiter. I want to send the string as an SMS...

Comment: If you need to limit the char count, you can use `read(char[])` with appropriate-sized array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean with `<CR>` "Carriage Return", you should use `BufferedReader`:

```java
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inStream);
String line = null
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // do something with `line`

}
```

Comment: OP is reading from the serial port, if I got it right, so he really means CR as opposed to the host platform-specific line terminator.

Comment: but he tests for `\r` or `\n`, which are line terminators... so `readLine()` should do the trick

Comment: Yes, he edited the question... so it really does look now like he's doing too much work with that raw reading loop.